# Error : Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I looked around here in the " Can't set headers after they are sent." questions and found that this error occurs when res.render() get's called twice but I didn't find a definitive solution that can help me ...

in my case I need to validate the session every time there is a GET request to the index page and if there is a user in session display the index page with the relevant parameters ...

any thoughts?

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var Schemes = require('../library/dbModels.js');
var router = express.Router();


/* GET home page and preform validation on user */
router.get('/index',function(req, res){
  if(req.session && req.session.user)
  {
    Schemes.User.findOne({eMail:req.session.user.eMail},function(err,user) {
      if(!user)
      {
        req.session.reset();
        res.render('login',{error:"Please log in ..."})
      }
      else
      {
        res.locals.user=user;
        res.render('index',{user:user});
      }
    });
  }
  else{
    res.render('login',{error:"Please log in ..."})
  }
  res.render('index', { title: 'Index' });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Are you looking for `res.end()`?

Comment: Problem is in `res.render('index', { title: 'Index' });`. So either if or else, it will be executed, so you r getting this error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the last `res.render('index', { title: 'Index' });`, because this same action was performed in the `else` condition of `if(!user)`.

```
router.get('/index',function(req, res){
    if(req.session && req.session.user) {
        Schemes.User.findOne({eMail:req.session.user.eMail}, function(err,user) {
            if(!user) {
                req.session.reset();
                res.render('login',{error:"Please log in ..."})
            } else {
                res.locals.user=user;
                res.render('index',{user:user, title: 'Index' });
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.render('login',{error:"Please log in ..."})
    }
});
```

Comment: that did it thank you !!! (I didn't notice that at first ....)------>Iv'e added a small fix for your answer to my question ... Thank you very much !!!!!!

Comment: Glad to help you.